# "I am extremely smarter than you."

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, syntactic-analysis, comparatives, comparisons

Is "I am extremely smarter than you." a grammatically OK sentence?

It sounds awkward, but is there a grammatical issue?

Please note that I am not asking if it could sound better, nor am I asking for suggestions on an equivalent but better written phrase. Is this statement grammatically acceptable?

Comment: It does seem that only a restricted set of adverbs can modify comparatives. The tricky part is deciding if this set is grammatically restricted, or partially restricted by non-grammatical factors. Mention of this is made here (apparently it is much the same for adverbs modifying "too"): ["too and too much"](http://www.englishpractice.com/words/too-and-too-much/), which lists *much, a lot, far, a little, a bit, rather*. Apparently, this class of adverbs may be called "[adverbs of degree](http://www.englishgrammar.org/adverb-degree/)" (although I'm not sure; that might include other things too).

Comment: Yeah, apparently "adverbs of degree" does include various words, including according to some ["extremely."](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/adverbs-degree/) So it doesn't seem to be a helpful classification here.

Comment: Another adverb that is acceptable modifying "too" or comparatives is *almost*.

Answer (score 3):

The statement is grammatically acceptable. (You can change "extremely"for "much" or "slightly"and see how it works ).It's the choice of an adverb that makes the sentence strange.

Comment: Are you sure?  I would tend to think that one cannot modify a *comparative* adjective (probably not the technical term; I mean 'smarter' as opposed to 'smart') using the adverb 'extremely'.  I agree that one could use 'much' or 'slightly', but I'm not sure that's conclusive; it is clear that one can say immodestly that "I am extremely smart", but I think that one cannot say "I am much smart."

Comment: On the other hand, I've just checked and the OED does list 'very much' as one of the meanings of 'extremely' (http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/67170#eid4882154 ), so maybe I'm just overreacting to the awkward sound and making up rules that don't exist.

Comment: @LSpice: I would say the sentence is more that just awkward; for me it's barely acceptable at the most. The tricky part is explaining this, and figuring out how the explanation relates to grammar (if it does).

Comment: @sumelic Exactly, that's precisely why I asked the question. It just doesn't seem quite right, but it's hard to tell if it's actually wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It would sound absurd when you modify *superlatives* with adverbs such as very/extremely/much, etc.

> I am the extremely smartest guy in the world.

It doesn't work as [*superlative*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superlative) means:

> The highest extent or degree of something.

I think the same way of thinking should be applied to *comparatives*. When you use *comparatives*, you have a certain extent or degree in your mind higher or lower, albeit abstract, and you want to express it.

*Comparitive* is defined in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comparative) as:

> of or relating to the form of an adjective or adverb that is used to
>   indicate *more of a particular quality*

You want to express "*more of a particular quality*" and adding an adverb such as *extremely* can be a duplicate of comparatives.

That's why you don't use the adverb *very* to modify comparatives.

There are exceptional adverbs that are allowed *by definition* to modify comparatives such as:

Still, even, much, far, a lot, a way (colloquial)

[*Still*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/still) has the following definition in Wiktionary:

> (degree) To an ***even*** greater degree. Used to modify comparative
>   adjectives or adverbs.

Those other examples have *the same definition and usage examples* as still. Extremely doesn't.

***Note***: You can google *extremely + comparative* and get some hits. I don't think people would be unable to understand when they are uttered. .